# How to find adapter sequence

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-alignment

I have this GSE dataset ( GSE104279 ) (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE104279)

I want to run cutadapt, but how would I find the adapter sequence so I can run cutadapt?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitive answer is the sequencing institute/lab. They know what protocol/chemistry etc. was used.

If you don't have access to that a number of tools check for known adapter sequences. Run e.g. [FASTQC](https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/), which will tell you the proportions of adapter sequence found. Tools like [TrimGalore](https://github.com/FelixKrueger/TrimGalore) can also autodetect the most common adapters.

UPDATE:
I checked 2M reads from one run of your dataset and it seems to me that it was uploaded already preprocessed:

[image: per-sequence-quality]
[image: length-distribution]
[image: adapter-content]

Check all your samples, but I don't see a need to do any preprocessing if all of them look like this.

Comment: Thank you! @BastianSchiffthaler. That was helpful. I wanted to make matrix table of these read, how can I join columns of these read into one table in this case? because I tried to make them collection, it failed. also when you uploaded them did you upload them as fastqsanger.gz or as different format?

Comment: I updated the question with the photo of table that want to make (it is an example not the real data that I linked) @BastianSchiffthaler

Comment: I would say this is really a separate question, but essentially the easiest pipeline is: Download the fastq.gz, run [salmon](https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon) with a human reference (there are tons of tutorials for this). In `R`, use the [tximport](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/tximport/inst/doc/tximport.html) package to create a count matrix.

Comment: Thank you @BastianSchiffthaler. I used join column on collection in galaxy, why it did not work? I want to do it in galaxy.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there, I don't use Galaxy. Please submit a new question for this so you get help.